# Adding subdomain constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-6

I currently have the following line in route.rb file
`resources :pages, only: %i[index show create]`

Moving forward I want my users to access `pages#show` through a dedicated subdomain. So I've added the following line:

```
constraints subdomain: 'pages' do
 get '/:id' =>  'pages#show'
end
```

(I'm planning on keeping both routes for retro-compatibility)

Which allows users the access it through pages.mydevdomain.com/my-page-id
When doing so in development environment I get the following message:

```
To allow requests to pages.mydevdomain.com, add the following to your environment configuration:
config.hosts << "pages.mydevdomain.com"
```

Which I've done and it works. However if I got to `http://pages.mydevdomain.com` then I get to see the whole app I built which means that this subdomain isn't just for `pages#show` like I wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of this constraint is that you can only access the pages#show action through the subdomain. But you are also allowing access using the `resources` method. So the constraint has no effect.

You are not restricting access to any other controller. Maybe you want to wrap your routes like this:

```rb
constraints subdomain: '' do
  resources :pages, only: %i[index show create]
end

constraints subdomain: 'pages' do
  get '/:id' =>  'pages#show'
end
```

Comment: The main issue is that not only `resources :pages, only: %i[index show create]` is accessible through the subdomain but the entire app.

Comment: Like I said. If you want to restrict access to the entire application you need put a constraint around those routes as well.